# How to get VPC ID of the VPC to which my vpc endpoint service belongs to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I am confused about how to get VPC ID for a VPC to which an endpoint service belongs to?

I can see several VPCs under "Your VPCs" menu, each having a VPC ID. Under "Endpoint Services", I can see our endpoint service and information about it like 'Service ID', 'Network Load Balancers ARNs', 'DNS names', 'Service name', etc. However, I don't see the VPC ID of the VPC in which my endpoint service resides.

Can anyone please help with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way I could figure out was to get the Load Balancer ARN from "Endpoint Service" and then use it to  get the corresponding Load Balancer in "EC2". It will have the VPC ID.